# Captured variables in ParameterizedThreadStart

Tags: c#, multithreading, captured-variable

I have the following code that creates 10 threads which in turn write out messages to the console:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread((threadNumber) =>
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread: {0}, Line: {1}", threadNumber, j));
                }                           
            });
        thread.Start(i);
    }
}
```

My understanding is that `ParameterizedThreadStart` takes an object for which a copy of the reference is sent to the thread. If that is the case since I have not made a local copy of `i` within each loop all new threads would point to the same memory location meaning certain thread numbers could be 'missed out'. Having run this though (and even against a larger number of threads/sleep times) each value of `i` has its own thread. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't applied anything *deferred* or "captured" in the sense of creating an anonymous function that would wrap `i`.

The lambda function here does not reference `i` anywhere and its state is completely internalized/contained so no issues here:

```
(threadNumber) =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread: {0}, Line: {1}", threadNumber, j));
    }                           
});
```

The `Start` call here:

```
thread.Start(i);
```

Passes `i` by value (i.e. copies its value) because it is a "value type" and it's not captured in any kind of anonymous function. In this sense, it is passed as any normal `struct` would to any normal method (because this is exactly what is happening).

---

If instead you had written your lambda as this using `i` instead of your `threadNumber`:

```
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Thread: {0}, Line: {1}", i, j));
    }                           
});
```

Then you would be in trouble. In this case `i` is referring to the original variable location and will be evaluated whenever the thread executes. This means it *could* be the current value of `i` when it was created (unlikely just due to processing times), or the value set later on in the `for` loop, or the last possible value `10`, and quite possibly have the number skip or shared between iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Chris, it was the copy by value part that was tripping me up!

Comment: @Maverick note even in the "error" case he gives, you can still get the correct result by adding a line `var i1 = i` before the closure, and using `i1` everywhere you use `i`.